# Understanding HLS implementation?

Tags: file-upload, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, video-upload

User will upload the videos from browser which need to be stored on server and playback. First understanding from google suggest I need to go for HTTP live streaming(HLS) here.
But I am not sure how it works internally ?

There are three components in above workflow i.e. client/server/data store for saving and retrieving videos.

**Save flow :**
I believe I need to plugin the HLS client for sending the streaming data.
Does Client in itself divide the file into chunks while sending and maintain the chaining of these chunk where each chunks points to next one ? something like this as I believe server is dumb and will work in same fashion as http upload functionality and no other intelligence is required here ?
But not sure how HLS server side component works here i.e. Will it save as single file or single file is split in to multiple files and then saved on disk ?
I believe it store the file as single file like regular http upload file ?

**Retrieval part**
In normal regular http file download, client asks for file data and server sends the response back in chunks but all response chunks are sent back against the same request.

I believe in case of HLS , its pull based where client initiate the pull request for each stream request. In each chunk pull request client gets the file name of next chunk and send the request to serverthe relevant chunk from single file for each poll request etc ?  So for server its kind of regular http file download request and all intelligence lies with client

Comment: Not clear _"User will upload the videos from browser"_ does this mean they select a stored file (MP4) to upload to your server for others to watch whenever they want (eg: on site visit)... Or you meant to say _"user will send their webcam stream to my server and I want others to watch it live in realtime"_? Which site/app listed here is similar to your expected result: (a) Youtube with video upload for anytime viewing or (b) Skype/Xoom for realtime streaming. HLS might not be needed if we know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It can be any one of them i.e. uploading the stored file or streamed through web cam

Comment: So what happens if the manifest file is being written while the player is accessing it? Is it written in such a way that the changes on the server side are atomic? A large manifest file (.m3u8) might take several milliseconds to get and there is a high likelyhood it may be "half-written" when the player gets it. Does the standard require the player to handle this - or does it just choke?

Answer (score 0):

Save flow:  When you upload a video, it must be converted into HLS format. You can use FFMPEG to do that. You'll end up creating manifest files, and all the segments of the video.

Retrieval part:
The player will read the manifest file to know which segments to request. I've written a post on how HLS playback works with the manifest files:  https://api.video/blog/video-trends/what-is-hls-video-streaming-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: "it must be converted into HLS format.." Is it down by javascript client or need to be done at backend ?

Comment: 100% backend. This requires computing power - not someone's iphone. :)